# SELECT categories from a mapping table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables :

```
categories:
ID, category
"1","Cars"
"2","Trucks"
"3","Bikes"
"4","Planes"
"5","Boats"

users:
ID, username
"1","john"
"2","bob"
"3","billy"

users_categories:
ID, userid, categoryid
"1","1","2"
"2","1","5"
"3","2","3"
"4","3","2"
"5","3","4"
"6","3","5"
```

Q1. What I want is :

```
john,Trucks,Boats
bob,Bikes
billy,Trucks,Planes,Boats
```

I've come to this. A Concat of the categories would do.

```
SELECT U.`username`, (SELECT C.`category` FROM `categories` C LEFT JOIN `users_categories` UC ON C.`ID` = UC.`categoryid` WHERE U.ID = UC.userid) FROM  `users` U
```

But I get #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Q2. Is there a better way to structure this ? There won't be more than 50-100 categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use **[`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)** to achieve what you want

```
SELECT  a.username,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.category)
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN users_categories b
            On a.Id = b.userID
        INNER JOIN categories c
            ON b.categoryID = c.ID
GROUP BY a.ID
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73184/1)

Comment: I'm wondering why the execution plan on SqlFiddle states `using temporary; using filesort` when it can generate the results in the sort order?

Answer (score 0):

if you can live with having the categories as a comma separated string, you can use the GROUP_CONCAT function.

Let's see (I've never tried myself in mysql)

```
select u.username,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.Category order by c.Category SEPARATOR ',')
from users u
     join usersCategories uc 
       on u.ID = uc.userID
     join Categories c 
       on c.ID = uc.CategoryID
```

You might have to adjust it to MySQL specific syntax, sorry.